# Request for link to my deleted answer(s)

Tags: support, search, deleted-answers, post-ban

I am unable to find my deleted answers. They don't show up under my list of answers. I am trying to "fix" my deleted answers to work towards getting my answer ban lifted.

To clarify, I am not asking how to undelete answers. I see other posts on how to undelete. This is different because I can't even find my deleted answers.

Would it be possible for a diamond moderator to provide the links for my deleted answers?

Comment: It would be nice if  the decision made years ago on the following Meta Stack Exchange post would be reconsidered: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297)

Comment: Deleted answers, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/a/24048481) [2](//stackoverflow.com/a/22850779) [3](//stackoverflow.com/a/22850662) [4](//stackoverflow.com/a/22850559) [5](//stackoverflow.com/a/21208046) [6](//stackoverflow.com/a/12965797) [7](//stackoverflow.com/a/12752031))

Comment: @SamuelLiew #s 5, 6 and 7 were deleted when their question was deleted. Hope they don't count for the autoban algo. There's nothing OP can do about those.

Comment: ≥ 10k rep users can see their deleted posts by putting `user:userID deleted:yes` in the search where userID is your userID

Comment: @Jeremy In this particular case, five of the seven answers were deleted by the owner themselves - and one of the other two wasn't even an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You indeed won't be able to find them, as they are way, way older than the 60 day limit imposed on the 'deleted recent answers' view you have access to.

Here are the ones that are on questions that are themselves not deleted:

- [IntelliJ show JavaDocs tooltip on mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-show-javadocs-tooltip-on-mouse-over/24048481#24048481)
- [Manipulating an Array into a New Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850690/manipulating-an-array-into-a-new-array/22850779#22850779)
- [Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14 to dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850574/fri-mar-30-000000-cet-14-to-dd-mm-yyyy/22850662#22850662)
- [Accessing fields in objects in list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850522/accessing-fields-in-objects-in-list-of-objects/22850559#22850559)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751960/java-reading-path-from-configuration-file/12752031#12752031 (question is now deleted)

Comment: I had a look at all of his answers, deleted or otherwise, and I say SOMETHING'S WRONG HERE. The only plausible explanation is answers on deleted questions count for the answer ban. If so, it means he cannot fix it, and requires extensive mod help with disassociation.

Comment: @Joshua You will not be able to see them all. And, if there are that many, then the system is working as advertised.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are too many people who downvote answers to bad questions. The resulting effect is unfair.

Comment: @Joshua I don't necessary disagree with that. Although if you're only answering bad questions then, well, that's still behaviour that requires correcting.

Comment: @Joshua Is it really that unfair that the system punishes posting answers that shouldn't be posted?

Comment: @jpmc26: Because people downvote the answers based solely on the question, it is no measure of the poster's ability and therefore no measure on the very next answer to a good question. If the question's bad the delete question will take care of the answer anyway.

Comment: @Joshua But posting an answer to a poor question reflects poorly on the answerer's judgement. If they are consistently posting answers to questions that we wish to discourage from being posted in the first place, they're *actively harming SO* by encouraging bad questions. I don't see punishing that as unfair in the slightest. Maybe it's not the "officially accepted norm" and maybe downvoting is the wrong way to go about it, but I honestly don't see how you can complain that it's "unfair" for bad behavior to give the user a negative result.

Comment: It's times like these I wish there was something in the works to make it so questions should only show up if approved by enough people.  That'd sure help the curating and stop the flood of poor questions.

Comment: @jpmc26 Do you think that downvoting answers to bad questions is working? *Is it* discouraging bad questions?

Comment: I've had folks ding my questions because they considered them (sometimes correctly, sometimes, not), insufficiently "researched." Other times, I think it's a bit petty. This site seems to have a basic bias against asking questions. Look at the top tier, with six-figure reps, and 1-figure question counts. I have a lot more questions than answers, which, I guess, means I'm a Sans-Culotte. I come for answers that I don't have, and I appreciate y'all. Your answers save me multiple times a week. I just feel that I need to walk a mile in someone's shoes before I can judge them.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1394393

Comment: @Froopy I agree that this sounds nice, but in my experience bad questions are downvoted much, much more than good questions are upvoted. I'd be afraid my questions would never be visible not because they aren't good, but because they're too niche or too sophisticated for 99.9% of SO users.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks. That mindset (the shame and whatnot) explains a lot. 99% of my questions get answered without me needing to ask them, which is the best outcome. I don’t think that having unanswered questions (“stump the experts”) is something to be proud of (I have a couple). BTW: I like your tagline.

Answer (score -2):

You can see your own deleted answers if they received any votes even after the 60 days limit with a work around.

All you have to do is to search through your reputation tab, you will find a link on the first rep gain/lose event entry.

See this [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298203/307083) for details.

Comment: While an interesting potential work around, this is not a reliable way to find deleted answers, because aside from the fact that you may not know when it was deleted (and thus may take forever to find them if you have a lot of rep, and thus a lot of entries), you may have zero-score deleted answers that were never voted upon.

Comment: 3 of the answers I linked were never even voted on and can't be found in the OP's reputation history.